# Max Hamming Distance

Tags: algorithms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comp Sci Math; Hamming Distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68294/comp-sci-math-hamming-distance)

I have been set a task:

What is the maxium possble Hamming distace between
two noes from level i in an n-cube? Provide an explanation for your
answer!

Comment: Asked and answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/68294/15941)

Comment: Well spotted, @Dilip. Voting to close as a dup.

Answer (score 2):

The discription fore homework says "show sufficient effort". Well I don't think that this is the case... ;)

Anyway I think it would help yourself if you draw a square (which is a 2-cube) and try to find out the distance between the nodes (don't forget the diagonale). Afterwords try to generalize it to a n-cube.

Comment: What exactly is a "level"?

Comment: @David, The word *level* is in the statement of the homework. Presumably the homework is given in the frame of a course. But *level* was not defined in the course?

Comment: @David Don't you think that **you** should tell us, what a "level" is? Hardly anything standard! If coerced to answer, I would hazard a guess that level $i$ consists of the nodes at Hamming distance $i$ from a given reference node, but that is just a guess. Think "triangle inequality", but also remember that there is a maximum to the Hamming distance on an $n$-cube. Or that "level" $i$ is (if I guessed correctly) the same set of points that forms "level" $n-i$ when viewed from the exact opposite reference point.